# Using Windows Azure Active Directory for Public Users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I understand that WAAD is meant for internal organizational accounts. I understand the concepts behind ADFS and other "AD in the cloud" related topics. But is there really anything that is preventing WAAD to be used for public accounts?

I want to build a public facing web site using ASP.Net MVC. I will use WIF to implement claims authentication and plan to use ACS as a claims federation provider. I want to allow the end users to login using Social Network Accounts (out of the box with ACS). But I also want to allow users to register their own user name and passwords for my web site. Can I use WAAD for this part?

Of course I could build my own custom STS. Or I could use Thinktecture IdentityServer for this purpose. But there are some clear advantages of sticking with WAAD:

- simplicity (to set up WAAD as a STS to ACS takes just few clicks)
- performance, security, reliability guaranteed by Azure SLAs

Is there any disadvantage to this approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You certainly can use WAAD for creating user accounts. You, also of course, have to force users to use e-mail style logins.

There is however one (BIG in my opinion) disadvantage of WAAD against ThinkTecture's Identity Server: WAAD **does not have** a user registration / password management / password reset flow.

---

**UPDATE (29.07.2014)**

Today WAAD provides Self-service-password-reset as part of [Premium Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn532272.aspx). However still no self-service-user-registration. Frankly I do not expect to ever see self service user registration, as WAAD is targeting enterprises, and not your specific scenario.

---

To implement mentioned flow in WAAD, you have to developed your own MVC App from scratch, that uses the Graph API for all mentioned scenarios.

On the other side, you have Identity Server, which has thousands of downloads, which is developed by **the** Gurus of Claims based authentication and security. Identity server has very rich and easy to use extensible structure. While it also does not provide the user registration and password reset flows out of the box, it is already an MVC 4 application with very rich extensibility points.

Setting up an Identity server for run in Azure is also extremely easy. And setting up Identity Server as Identity provider in Azure ACS is just couple of clicks on the management portal.

You say that WAAD is SLA backed, highly available, etc. But your Identity Server deployment on a Cloud Service will be SLA backed too if use at least 2 instances of a Web Role.

If I have to chose whether to extend Identity Server to support user registration etc, or to create entirely new application from scratch that uses WAAD GRaph API for that feature - I would use Identity Server.

Comment: is this still the condition of IdentityServer v2 (e.g. not having registration, pwd mgmt, reset)?

How would I do those things?  How about using MembershipReboot in conjuction with IdentityServer v2?  Is that possible, and if so, how?

Comment: to time there is still no ´self service´ password management. In the admin panel there is user password manager. There is sample implementation of MembersheepReboot in the GitHub repository of IdSvr2; https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2

Comment: Hello @astaykov any chages in AD for "External accounts" registration? thank you guys.

Comment: user registration - no.
self-service password reset - yes.
federating with externail identity providers - no.

Answer (score 3):

As of September this year the Azure B2C preview is there. This should satisfy the scenerio of self service user registration and different identity providers (Facebook, Google, Microsoft...). These are all serviced from AzureAD. 
[Azure AD b2c](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-overview/)

There is als a complete MVC sample available
[Azure AD b2c MVC Sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/)

Comment: Hi, Azure AD B2C is terrific but it cannot be used for SPA/Angular type applications https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-limitations , However Identityserver v3 supports it https://cedric-dumont.com/tutorials/identityserver-v3-membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix-it-introduction/

Comment: @KaranBhandari Why cannot I use SPA/Angular with AD B2C? I don't find an explicit entry about it on the FAQ. Thanks.

Comment: If you have the opportunity go for the server side auth and not for the Angular implementation. We have been using the adal-angular library for a while and this has proven to be tricky. The bearer token is very limited and with each upgrade of the library bugs / issues have been introduced and fixed.

Comment: @Reuel Ramos Ribeiro Azure B2C can work from SPA/Angular applications provided they are served by Nodejs/.NET MVC/WebAPI because SPA by themselves cannot guard a secret such as client ID, additionally above mentioned backends support OpenID Connect middleware. Right now even the custom UI 's javascript is disabled https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/12557409-azure-b2c-custom-user-attribute-validation-like-us