# Using Azure AD for user authentication in a game

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm in the process of designing a HTTP REST Web API for online services such as matchmaking, chat, user profiles, etc. These services will form a backbone for future games that are going to be developed at my company.

As these services are going to be accessed over the internet, the user accessing them needs to be authenticated and then authorized to access the said services.

From what I've read, googled, asked, etc, separating the security stuff out of the business code is a "good thing". Many blogs suggested handling these kind of problems via a Secure Token Service (STS), and as I do have a trial subscription with Windows Azure, I was just wondering if all of this would be possible with Azure Active Directory?

Is is possible to let users register new accounts via AAD, and log in from a native desktop application via AAD?

If this is not possible, do you guys propose any solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Windows Azure Active Directory for Public Users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059118/using-windows-azure-active-directory-for-public-users)

Comment: Just to add - yes, you can authenticate against AAD in a Desktop Application (WinForms, WPF) and Mobile Devices (yet only Windows 8 based).

Comment: Ok thats good to know, thanks. I just want ask, should a browser window be used to allow the user to enter their credentials or can this be done via the native app?

Comment: Generally yes, but this is handled by the library - [Azure Authentication Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj573266.aspx). And the library is extremely simple and easy to use!

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I saw on the sample site that they are going to remove the ability for an application to authenticate via native user/password credentials. Does this mean that the app will have to pop up a web browser for the user to authenticate themselves?

Comment: where did you read that? One thing is to authentication `application`, other thing is to authenticate `user`. And for user authentication there are no plans (that I know) to remove simple user/password authentication. Moreover, AAD supports OAuth 2.0, SAMLP and WS-Federation passive protocols, which all support simple user/password authentication.

Comment: At the top of this page (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AAL-Native-Application-to-f8971f47) it shows that the library no longer supports the feature. Do you maybe have a section I can read up on how to do it, maybe via REST API's?

Comment: you need to read the [Authentication via Browser Dialog](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AAL-Native-Application-to-fd648dcf). And Authentication via User Credentials is natural to be dropped off, because the scenario is fully supported by OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. So if I want to authenticate my users via the usual username/password dialog implemented in the native app I should research OAuth a bit more?

Comment: no, you should use the AAL `and` read more. [CloudIdentity](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/) is a good start.

Comment: I should also add that I want to run this program on various platforms, eg. MacOS, Linux, and Windows. Should I edit the original question?