# Azure website brought up login.microsoftonline.com (Sign in with your work or school account)

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a website done in ASP.Net MVC which hosted in Azure websites and it will try to connect to a VM machine hosted on Azure which has MongodDB installed and running. tt will need to connect to port 27017.

When I tested on my local machine, I can connect to the VM MondgoDB no issues, then I published to Azure web site and it brought up www.microsoftonline.com login, saying sign in the Azure Active directory on the title bar and prompted login for "sign in with your work or school account.

It seems to me Azure has certain fire wall or ??? to prevent port 27017 from the web server (xxxxx.azurewebsites.net). Any ideas?

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the Azure AD login page because the website has been setup with Authentication / Authorisation to use Azure AD.

Log into the Azure Portal and find your Website instance > Click 'Configure' tab.  Scroll down until you find the 'authentication / authorization' section and click on the 'Remove' button to disassociate your website with Azure AD.

Comment: Simon, thanks for helping, it worked, but I have another question. If I want to use Active directory in this case, how do I set it up? do you have any sample link (of course I can Google too). So I have a list of user/pw set up first before they can access the web site. Or do I have a way for them to register to the active directory online first?

Comment: Greg - best would be to look at this SO response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16059118/using-windows-azure-active-directory-for-public-users